# White squares in WMTS for OS Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, wmts

A WMTS connection I have had in QGIS for some time now is currently not working as expected. I have not had this issue before and I have not changed the URL connection.

The connection in question is for OS Open Raster from ESRI's Vector Tile Services and the connection URL is:

> http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Raster/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=99417257241d59ec

**Here is A GIF to highlight the issue:**

[image]

Comment: Does the preview for the wmts layer on arcgis.com have the same issue?

Comment: @csk yes it did so I assume it was a maintenance or server issue from the source? It is now working as expected.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Looking at the same data through a different dataviewer (which this one conveniently has through arcgis.com) is a good way to check if the issue is with the data or with the program. I will post an answer recommending that approach for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaps in a tile layer can be caused by an issue from the data source. If the problem is on the data provider's end, there's nothing you can do to fix it in QGIS. To check if the problem is with the data or only in QGIS, try to see the data through another viewer or program. In this case, since the layer is hosted by arcgis.com, it can be previewed there. Here's the link for that:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?basemapUrl=http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Raster/MapServer?cacheKey=b86533914ecad07c

I found that by pasting the WMTS service URL into my browser, then cutting off the end of it, so it was just

http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Raster/MapServer/

That link takes you to a summary page, which has links to to view the data in three different ways: ArcGIS JavaScript, ArcGIS.com, and WMTS.

If the data has the same or similar gaps when viewed through a different data viewer, it means the issue is on the end of the data provider. Contact the data provider and notify them of the issue. In this case the issue resolved itself, presumably because the data provider noticed the issue and fixed it.